# 1/16 bit to cut through 1/2" MDF

Tags: wood, drill-bits

I need to use a 1/16 router bit to cut through a 1/2" piece of MDF. Is there a bit with a long enough shank that will allow me to do that or what are my options? I am curing small letters with a cnc machine and the 1/8" bit is too large and distorts the letters.

Comment: Can you change the CNC pathway to move the outline out 1/16"?

Answer (score 5):

Good luck not snapping the bit, which is the practical reason such bits are hard to find.

1/4" cutting length might allow (with proper registration) cutting from both sides (have to mirror the cutting file when flipped, of course.)

Looking (as I usually do, since supply is much better) for end mills, **1/16" end mill extra long** brings up several options, including 1/2, 5/8. 3/4 and 0.95 inch cutting lengths.

**1/16" router bit extra long** does get some useful hits as well, including some with 1 or even 1.5 inch cutting length, but those (at least the ones I looked at) are pointy cones, not straight bits - if your software understands the shape, you'll break fewer bits, but still be able to detail the surface.

As far as I recall we are still not a shopping site, so I'll provide keywords but not links to products.

In either case, **wear your safety glasses** and expect to break some bits, or change the design/process to cut with a larger bit, or a laser, or something better suited - long skinny router bits (and endmills) do break in real life.

Making the small letters out of thinner material would be an obvious alteration towards success.

Comment: I am sure if you take shallow passes it will not break the bit. We have to make shallow passes here at the high school when we use our 1/16" bit. We never had a issue. But at the same time, a 1/16" bit so long, that have got to be a very easy thing to break.